# GCP Org policy to restrict deletion of object and bucket in cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to create GCP Org policy to restrict deletion of object and bucket in cloud storage.

I have a bucket and few objects in it. I would like t control the deletion part via an org policy even if the project has cloud storage admin rights for that bucket.

not able to see any.

Comment: The GCP Organization policies are fixed by Google ... you can't create new GCP Org Policy definitions.  It doesn't appear that there is an existing Org Policy that would restrict deletion of an object or a bucket.  I would consider two options ... 1: Don't grant object delete or bucket delete permissions (roles) against the bucket or 2: Review/consider retention policies.  This ensures no deletion of data but doesn't use Org Policy ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud now offers IAM Deny policies
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-access

These use resource tags, and when applied to resources like buckets, take precedence over normal IAM policies.